# Ubuntu 16.04 - Not recognising second monitor

Tags: 16.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I'm trying to connect my second monitor to my Dell Latitude laptop while using Ubuntu 16.04. It works fine in Windows but Ubuntu doesn't even seem to recognise it when I run the `xrandr --listmonitors` command.

I've tried seeing if there are any additional drivers I need but since my laptop only has Intel built-in graphics, all of the documentation for Nvidia drivers was of no help to me.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be a great help.

Comment: how are you connecting the laptop? can you try a different cable or a different port?

Comment: I'm using a HDMI cable and my laptop only has 1 HDMI port.

Comment: what standard is the HDMI cable? which HDMI standard has the laptop. I had, for example problems, with the Raspberry Pi 4 and older HDMI cables...